# Webserver on Arduino Mega with Ethernet Shield

Tags: arduino-mega, web-server, ethernet-shield

I am working with an official Arduino Mega. I have mounted an officiel Ethernet Shield rev 2.

Everything works great, i have wrote a very basic webserver.

I wanted to host a bootstrap css file on my webserver. This file has a size of about 150 kilo-bytes. So i have inserted an SD card on the Ehternet Shield. I have put my css file on this SD card.

I am writing the content of my css file with this code:

```
File myFile = SD.open("bootstrap.min.css");
if (myFile) 
{
    byte clientBuf[2048];
    int clientCount = 0;              
    while (myFile.available()) 
    {
        clientBuf[clientCount] = myFile.read();
        clientCount++;

        if(clientCount > 2048-1)
        {
            client.write(clientBuf,2048);
            clientCount = 0;
        }                
     }
     if(clientCount > 0) client.write(clientBuf,clientCount);            
     myFile.close();
 }
```

It works, but it is very slow.
It takes about 30-40 seconds to load file into my browser.
I have tried to change clientBuf size but this is the optimal value i've set.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: you should set `Expires:` header to let the browser cache the file. and set the `content-length` header to let the browser know how many bytes to expect. https://github.com/jandrassy/Regulator/blob/8262f28b7452df0b75aa6c5a7bc676e14cd0cd26/Regulator/WebServer.ino#L112

Comment: I agree but it will be slow for first load...

Comment: sorry, my largest file is only 10 kB. can you load framework files from Internet?